# Append to Select not working in Chrome?

Tags: jquery

How to make this simple code work in chrome?

```
 $('#teser').append(new Option('6','OptSix' ,true));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/77c92wyv/

Its working fine in IE and FFX

Comment: just use `new Option(name, id, true, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an option as a jQuery object. It will definitely work anywhere:

```
$('#teser').append(buildOption(6, 'OptSix'));

function buildOption(value, text) {
  return $("<option/>", {
    value: value,
    text: text
  })
}
```

Comment: need a `return` in the function

Comment: @charlietfl oh, sure! Got used to CoffeeScript ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
$('#teser').append(new Option('OptSix','6' ,true, true));
```

and it should work.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option for correct usage of `Option()`

---

Notice the third argument

> `defaultSelected`
>   A boolean that sets the *selected **attribute***, the default is false. **A value of true does not set the option to selected**.

Comment: bingo!    https://jsfiddle.net/77c92wyv/3/   i am not sure i understand the differences between defaultSelected  and Selected

Comment: @user648026 you still have the text/value inverted (*when compared to the hardcoded values*). First argument is the text and second is the `value` of the `option`.

Comment: @user648026 the `defaultSelected` adds the attribute `selected` but does not set the relevant property. It is just how the added html will look like (*it will have the `selected` attribute*). See the html from the dev tools in each case and you will get it.